# React-native infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am build a replica of the 2048 game.

I am working on the animations right now and I seem to get infinite re-renders for some reason when updating the state with any kind of array.

It seems that passing anything but an array to 'setAppearAnimations' works fine.

Thanks in advance :)

```
const GameProvider = (props) => {
  const [appearAnimations, setAppearAnimations] = useState([])

  const addAppearAnimation = (animation) => {
    const newAppearAnimations = appearAnimations.concat([animation])
    console.log(newAppearAnimations)
    setAppearAnimations(newAppearAnimations)
  }
```

```
const Piece = ({ piece }) => {      
   const { value, prevX, prevY, x, y, hasJustAppeared } = piece      
   let appearAnimation = 1
   useEffect(() => {
       //Add appear animation       
       if (hasJustAppeared) {
           appearAnimation = new Animated.Value(0)         
           addAppearAnimation(appearAnimation)
       }
     }, [])
```

Comment: Please show how you're calling `addAppearAnimation`.

Comment: So `addAppearAnimation` is defined in the `GameProvider` component, but here you call the function inside another functional component `Piece`. That seems like a problem.

Comment: I recommend just updating the question and putting your relevant code there instead of the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have changed the way the animation is being called and now this part works better. I appreciate the tip about the code and will remember it for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way the animations are being called so now i declare it inside A Piece component and start it inside a 'useEffect' inside it.

Comment: I meant to update your original question. You can click the `edit` button on your original question and put this text plus how your code looks there.

Comment: I have added the code in the original question, in anyway I managed to solve this problem, heading towards the next one. Thanks again for your time and help.